# Getting error-Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on null in

Tags: php

I tried to looked to same question/ answers but cant figure out.

WHEN I AM ACCESSING INDEX. IT GIVES ERROR

"Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on null in......"

----------------------------Code is------------------

-------------Page1- index.php

```
<?php
include 'inti_test.php';
$user_id =3;
$user = $getFromUserClass->userData($user_id);
?>
```

-------------------page2-inti_test.php

```
<?php

   $dsn = 'mysql:host=localhost; dbname=testdb';
    $user = 'root';
    $pass = 'mypass';
    try{
        $PDO = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass);
    }catch(PDOException $e){
        echo 'Connection error!' .$e->getMessage();
    }
//------------------------- 
class User{
protected $pdo;

function __construct($pdo){
$this->pdo =$pdo;
}

public function userData($user_id){
$stmt = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM `user_detail_master` WHERE 
`user_id`=:user_id");
$stmt->bindParam(":user_id", $user_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->execute();
return $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ); 
} 
}

//--------------------- 
global $pdo;
session_start();
$getFromUserClass = new User($pdo);

?>
```

Comment: `$PDO` and `$pdo` are __different__ variables.

Comment: You have `$PDO` for connection and using `$pdo`

Comment: First of all you must have to start `session` at very top of the page and second thing you make a typo mistake `$pdo` and `$PDO` are two differrent things.

Comment: Thanks guys, mistake on my part..yes its PDO pdo

Answer (score 0):

like that

```
<?php

   $dsn = 'mysql:host=localhost; dbname=testdb';
    $user = 'root';
    $pass = 'mypass';
    global $pdo;
    try{
        $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass);
    }catch(PDOException $e){
        echo 'Connection error!' .$e->getMessage();
    }
//------------------------- 
class User{
protected $pdo;

function __construct($pdo){
$this->pdo =$pdo;
}

public function userData($user_id){
$stmt = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM `user_detail_master` WHERE 
`user_id`=:user_id");
$stmt->bindParam(":user_id", $user_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->execute();
return $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ); 
} 
}

//--------------------- 

session_start();
$getFromUserClass = new User($pdo);

?>
```

Comment: Explain please what changes have you made and __why__.

Comment: I agree with your words at top comment